# Under which process android.content.Intent runs?

Tags: android, process, operating-system

I'm an Android newbie. I understood that, every application runs in android as a process I'm not able to visualize or imagine how I'm able to access the piece of code which android provides me while developing the app.

> import android.content.Intent;

How am I able to access these android classes like `Intent`, `Context`, `IntentFilter` and all? Where do they live (means under which process)?

Sorry if the question is too lame.

Comment: @ rm-rf star  follows this google docs links with basic app example that explain each and everything as you go through it https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where do they live (means under which process)?

They live in your process and in the process of every other Android SDK app.

When your app runs, Android forks a process for your app from a common process called the `zygote`. The `zygote` contains, among other things:

- The runtime environment (Dalvik or ART, depending on Android version)
- Common Java code, such as the framework classes that you list
- Common shared libraries, such as SQLite and OpenSSL

The fork is set up for Linux-style "copy on write" memory sharing. Your process shares all of those things listed above with every other process forked from the `zygote`.

If you see an `import` statement in your own code, the imported class is in your process, whether you got it from the `zygote` or from your own APK (e.g., your classes, classes from libraries).

Comment: So, when my app is forked from `zygote` process it would have the cloned memory copy (stack, heap(?), code segment) of what zygote had (mens the classes which are already been loaded.  What happens when `zygote` didn't had a chance to load the class say for an example `Intent` during it's flow? Will my app load the `Intent` class if it finds it for the first time during runtime? Or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: @rm-rfstar: " What happens when zygote didn't had a chance to load the class say for an example Intent during it's flow?" -- AFAIK, those are preloaded.

Comment: Will all "stack, heap, code" segment content would be available for the forked process?

Comment: @rm-rfstar: That is an Android internals question that is beyond the scope of my expertise. Bear in mind that in a bytecode language, "heap" will refer to both code (bytecode) and data (objects created). My understanding is that you don't get the stack, you do get the (binary) code, and you would get part of the heap (bytecode). The details, though, are well outside the realm of standard Android app development.